# What does this code do: static union MSVC_EVIL_FLOAT_HACK INFINITY_HACK = {{0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7F}};

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef INFINITY
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    union MSVC_EVIL_FLOAT_HACK
    {
        unsigned __int8 Bytes[4];
        float Value;
    };
    static union MSVC_EVIL_FLOAT_HACK INFINITY_HACK = {{0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7F}};
    #define INFINITY (INFINITY_HACK.Value)
#endif
```

I'm currently getting started with the Chipmunk physics engine and found this in a header file

INFINITY is used to set infinite momentum for objects, however I don't understand what this code above does!

Answer (score 15):

It sets INFINITY to the float value represented by the hex bits 0x7f800000, which is `+INF`. Visual Studio doesn't define INFINITY for some reason.

Comment: In addition, it is declared in reverse order {0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7F} because x86 uses little-endian.

Comment: Is that `+/-INF` in your answer? 'Cause I'm pretty certain that bit pattern is just `+Inf` :-)

Comment: Never mind, I'll fix it myself. I can't abide a wrong answer having so many votes :-)

Answer (score 6):

The code above effectively defines a floating-point constant with some very specific bytes representation.

Every `float` is represented with a set of bytes, but when you define `float` constants you're forced to use decimal representation and can't define a constant with value say `0xFFFFFFFF` (I don't know if that constant is a legal `float` number).

The code above bypasses that limitation - it first sets a byte array inside the union and then "accesses" the same byte array as if it was a `float` number. This by the way is illegal - only the union member previously set can be legally accessed, but it might work on that specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It create a variable INFINITY_HACK, of type MSVC_EVIL_FLOAT_HACK. it sets the Bytes array to have values of the respective hex values. It then converts those bytes to a floating-point number (union only allows you to use one of the underlying values within so by referencing .value it is converting the data that INIFITY_HACK points to, to float) by following the [IEEE-754 Floating-Point Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754) (note that the bytes are taken in reverse) for binary->float conversion.

There's a nice little calculator that can explain it if you don't know how it works:
http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html   (if you enter 7F800000, you'll get Infinity, but try entering 4048F5C2 (you'll get close to 3.14)  [This calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html) goes decimal->hex.

Answer (score 1):

Its a way to initialise the memory occupied by a float variable to 0x7f800000. As @Jim says, this is +infinity in the float.

The code is roughly equivalent to:

```
byte Bytes[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7F };
float Value;
memcpy(&Value, Bytes, 4);
#define INFINITY_HACK (Value)
```

First the original code defines a union that allows you to manipulate four bytes of memory as either an array of four bytes, or as a single float (which we assume also occupies four bytes):

```
union MSVC_EVIL_FLOAT_HACK
    {
        unsigned __int8 Bytes[4];
        float Value;
    };
```

Then it allocates an instance of the union named `INFINITY_HACK` and sets the values of its `Bytes` array to the hex values specified.:

```
static union MSVC_EVIL_FLOAT_HACK INFINITY_HACK = {{0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7F}};
```

This has the effect of initialising the float Value field because it also occupies the same memory as the byte array.

Finally it defines a proprocessor constant named `INFINITY` as the float value.